# Access controller properties within Ember Data Transform

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I like to access a controller property within Ember Data Transform. Is there anyway how to do that?

Perhaps a few words to my use case. I like to create a custom attribute 'encryptedStrings' and use DS.Transform to encrypt / decrypt the string with a given key by using Stanford Javascript Crypto Library. The key should by part a query param in the uri.

get method is defined in DS.Transform but I did not get further. Here the relevant parts of the code:

```
App.EncryptedStringTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
       var key = this.get('pollController.encryptionKey');
       return Ember.isNone(serialized) ? null : String( sjcl.decrypt( key , serialized) );
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
       var key = this.get('pollController.encryptionKey');
       return Ember.isNone(deserialized) ? null : String( sjcl.encrypt( key , deserialized) );
    }
});

App.PollController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    queryParams: ['encryptionKey'],
    encryptionKey: 'default'
});
```

Instead of

```
this.get('pollController.encryptionKey');
```

I also tried this ones:

```
console.log( this.get('controller.encryptionKey') );
console.log( this.get('controllers.poll.encryptionKey') );
console.log( this.get('controllers.pollController.encryptionKey') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting! I wonder whether it's a good idea to have the encryption key be so exposed to be in the URL. But, assuming this is what you want to do, instead of transforming the data as part of the serializer, I think what I would do is set the key as a property on the model (from the route where the queryParam is exposed). Then, have the unencrypted values be computed properties on the model that are derived based on the key and the encrypted values, which would just be regular `DS.attr()`. Computed properties [can be both getters and setters](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties) so if a new value is set on the unencrypted property, then you can just set the reencrypted value.

**Update:**

Here's an example of how you can write the computed property in a reusable way:

```
Ember.computed.encrypted = function(encryptedField, keyField) {
  return Ember.computed(encryptedField, keyField, function(key, decryptedValue) {
    var encryptKey = this.get(keyField), encryptedValue;
    //setter
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
      encryptedValue = Ember.isNone(decryptedValue) ? null : String( sjcl.encrypt( encryptKey , decryptedValue) );
      this.set(encryptedField, encryptedValue);
    }
    encryptedValue = this.get(encryptedField);
    return Ember.isNone(encryptedValue) ? null : String( sjcl.decrypt( encryptKey , encryptedValue) );
  });
};
```

Then, you can write your model like this:

```
App.SensitiveData = DS.Model.extend({
  encryptKey:      DS.attr('string'),
  encryptedField1: DS.attr('string'),
  encryptedField2: DS.attr('string'),
  decryptedField1: Ember.computed.encrypted('encryptedField1','encryptKey'),
  decryptedField2: Ember.computed.encrypted('encryptedField2','encryptKey')
});
```

**Update 2:**

You can set the encryption key on your model via the Route, like this:

```
App.SensitiveDataRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('sensitive-data', params.sensitive_data_id).then(function(sensitiveData) {
      sensitiveData.set('encryptKey', params.encryption_key);
      return sensitiveData;
    });
  }
});
```

Or, assuming the data isn't exposed via the route, but only through the controller, you can add an observer to the controller and set the value through the observer, like this (note, it's possible that this isn't even necessary and since the controller proxies to the model, as long as the attribute in the model matches the query param name specified in the controller, you don't even need to do the observer logic, I'd need to play around with it to say for sure):

```
App.SensitiveDataController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  queryParams: ['encryptionKey'],
  encryptionKey: null,

  updateEncryptKey: function() {
    this.set('encryptKey', this.get('encryptionKey'))
  }.observes('encryptionKey')
});
```

Comment: Having the key in the url as part of the fragment identifier has to benefits for my: 1. The user do not have to care about the encryption key when they like to share the content. They just have to share the url. 2. Browser did not send the fragment identifier to the server.Using computed properties is an interesting approach.

  But how to tell ember data just to send the computed properties to the server? I thought ember data just cares about non computed properties but did not tested yet.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, I think the rest of my answer should work. You definitely don't want to expose your controller within your serialization layer. I think adding the key to the model and then having the decryption/encryption happen through computed properties is a better route.

Comment: Was to late with adding the second part of my comment: How to tell ember data just to send the computed properties to the server? I thought ember data just cares about non computed properties but did not tested yet.

Comment: Hold on, I'll update my post with a description of how to do that.

Comment: Was that helpful at all?

Comment: I need some time for tests. The code look really, really great. But also accessing a controller property from a model seems to be a problem. this.get(keyField) is not defined. But I think this should be possible.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, you shouldn't access your controller from the model. The models should exist completely independently of the controller. The way you can provide the key to the model is through your route when you're initializing your model. I'll add an example for that also. The reason I passed both the fieldName and the key to the computed property is b/c if either one of those values change on the model, then you will want to recompute the decrypted value. Speaking of, you might need to add some error handling to the computed property in case the key doesn't have a value set.